# Obtain the general equation for a normal space

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following exercise:

> Compute the normal space to the variety 
>   $A = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3}: z=x^2+y^2; x=y\}$ in the point $(1,1,2)$

So I had no trouble calculating the normal vectors to this variety. We just need to calculate the derivative matrix and the lines will give us the normal vectors. They are $(2,2,-1) and (1,-1,0)$

When I looked on the answer in my book they give us

$\{(x,y,-\frac{x}{4}-\frac{y}{4}): x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}$

My question is: having my vectors how do I obtain this "form" of representation?

Comment: Anybody????????

Answer (score 0):

Whenever confronted with a situation such as this, I try to verify my answer before proceeding. In your case, we should notice that the points generated by the tips of your vectors satisfy the book's solution. 
$(2,2, -2/4 -2/4) = (2,2,-1)$ and $(1,-1,-1/4-(-1/4))=(1,-1,0)$

So how do they get their expression?
Notice that the solution is a plane, and theirs is in the form $(x,y,z)$, being an arbitrary point on the plane. You have two (linearly independent) vectors that also describe the plane.

Usually, when writing the equation of a plane we use a point and the normal vector. Using your two vectors, we can find the cross product between them to obtain the normal to the plane you describe in your solution. This vector was (calculated by my computer to be) $(-1,-1,-4)$. However, the orientation (not the magnitude) is our only concern, so I write this now as $(1,1,4)$ You should notice that in your solution (and the book's solution), the origin is a point which is contained in this plane. So we have a normal vector and a point $(0,0,0)$.

The equation of the plane is:
$a(x-x_0) + b(y-y_0) + c(z-z_0)=0 $

So we have:

$1*(x-0) + 1*(y-0) +4(z-0) = 0$

Which simplifies to:

$z=-1/4(x+y)$

Which is precisely the third co-ordinate of the book's solution.

(The first two co-ordinates, x and y, are free variables.)